# Outlook Emails I send look different in the app versus the browser. Mainly formatting and background color

Tags: html, email, outlook, gmail, html-email

Im sending an email with some basic formatting in it.  It displays fine in Gmail, and outlook on the browser.  But as soon as i open it up in either the Gmail app or outlook app it looks bad.

Here is the proper image:
[image: Proper looking from browser]

Here is the bad version that shows in apps:
[image: bad looking in apps]

Here is the HTML that is generated in browser for the pink bar for example of the proper looking version:

```
<td style="padding:20px" align="center" bgcolor="#facbe3">
   <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank">
   <img src="" alt="Follow Us On Facebook" style="height:40px;width:40px;margin-left:10px" 
      class="CToWUd">
   </a>
   <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank" >
   <img src="" alt="Follow Us On Instagram" style="height:40px;width:40px;margin-left:10px" 
      class="CToWUd">
   </a>
   <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank">
   <img src="" alt="Follow Us On Pintrest" style="height:40px;width:40px;margin-left:10px" 
      class="CToWUd">
   </a>
   <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank" >
   <img src="" alt="Visit Us On Youtube" style="height:40px;width:40px;margin-left:10px" 
      class="CToWUd">
   </a>
</td>
```

My MAIN concern is why the color is different.
Any help as to why it would change would be really appreciated. Thanks guys and gals

Comment: Hi there, it looks like you've only supplied the code for the social icons. Unfortunately it isn't a simple and single answer to fix everything, especially across different email clients.

Can you please post more code, preferably the entire section which you've provided in the screenshots.

Comment: Looks like your apps are in darkmode

Comment: Thank you so much, such a dumb thing to miss. I'm pretty new to email stuff and it totally slipped pass me to check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common email problem in general is that dark mode on browsers and phones can act weird and cause issues with background colors.

Comment: Thanks, I had solved this already a while ago but its definitly good to know

Answer (score 1):

I've requested more code in a comment to your original post as we need to see more code to see what is affecting the title, button and social media icons respectively.

Since you've supplied the social icons for now, it is still unclear what is causing the issue as margin is supported in the way you've used it, in both email clients.
However, I would make a small change to the way you've structured it.

It isn't ideal setting a margin on an image which is wrapped in a link. That effectively pushes the link out which can cause mis-clicks for the user. Not great!
Try this instead:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#facbe3" style="padding:20px">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="width:205px;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                       <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank">
                       <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40" alt="Follow Us On Facebook" style="height:40px;width:40px;" class="CToWUd">
                       </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                       <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank" >
                       <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40" alt="Follow Us On Instagram" style="height:40px;width:40px;" class="CToWUd">
                       </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                       <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank">
                       <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40" alt="Follow Us On Pintrest" style="height:40px;width:40px;" class="CToWUd">
                       </a>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                       <a href="" style="font-size:16px;text-decoration:none;color:#222d64" target="_blank" >
                       <img src="https://picsum.photos/40/40" alt="Visit Us On Youtube" style="height:40px;width:40px;" class="CToWUd">
                       </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

So wrap the table in another table and apply the padding & background colour to that wrapper and then set a width on the inner table which the table cells will then themselves divvy up the width of the wrapping table evenly, giving you spacing which will hold everywhere.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I was always curious why an email has so many nested tables. Thank you.

Comment: To be honest im a lot more concerned about why the background color is different in the two. does it matter what type of element i put the background color on?

Comment: It can do. I would avoid setting a background color on table rows. Tables, table cells and divs are fine.

Comment: I've only just realised, looking at your screenshot again and I notice Nathan pointed it out too but it looks like your test is using a dark mode device. Clients like Gmail will do an invert on colours to make them work for dark mode, basically not leaving you with a lot of options to fix. Other clients do give you some options. But that is why your colours look off in your test.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. I have given you the answer since it solved my formatting.  Can't believe i missed that dark mode was causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue and after 1 week of debuging and digging I found out that chrome and edge are rendering mails depending on system's theme chosen. So if outlook.live.com is dark mode, and system's theme is light (windows), your email body would be rendered in light mode, the other parts would be dark(outlook.live.com theme). So if u want to get same mails, system's theme and outlook.live.com theme should be both dark or light. This sucks. Firefox is working properly and firefox is depending on outlook.live.com theme chosen.